# How to update the duplicate records instead of deleting them

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table named **T1** with columns - **t_id, t_id_pk,t_version_ind**. **t_id_pk** is the primary key column. **t_version_ind** is the Flag column with values '**TRUE**' and '**FALSE**'.

I have duplicate records in the table **T1**.

column **t_version_ind** is having incremental values. I have duplicate records with same **t_id** values repeated multiple times. I also have duplicate records with **t_version_ind** as '**TRUE**'.

When I do a select, I'm having multiple records like this:

```
SELECT t_id,count(*) FROM T1 WHERE t_version_ind ='TRUE'
GROUP BY t_id 
HAVING count(*)>1;
```

| t_id | duplicate COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 3 |
| 103 | 2 |
| 104 | 4 |
| 105 | 5 |

SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE t_id='100' and t_version_ind ='TRUE', I'm getting duplicate records.

I don't want to delete the records which are duplicated. For one particular ID, I need to display
only one row with **t_version_ind** as 'TRUE'. I need to update the **t_version_ind** for the remaining duplicate rows to **FALSE**.

Need help in forming a SQL query using UPDATE statement. Thanks in advance!

| t_id_pk     | t_id     | duplicate COUNT|
| --------    | -------- | ----------------
53066  960023712 TRUE
7458   960023712 TRUE
604475 960023712 TRUE
604538 960023712 TRUE
604539 960023712 TRUE
604664 960023712 TRUE
599867 960023712 TRUE
599868 960023712 TRUE
599869 960023712 TRUE
599929 960023712 TRUE
599998 960023712 TRUE
1414272 960023712 TRUE

117051 960089122 TRUE
53706 960089122 TRUE
116926 960089122 TRUE
604635 960089122 TRUE
604636 960089122 TRUE
600018 960089122 TRUE
600019 960089122 TRUE
597652 960089122 TRUE
604312 960089122 TRUE
604313 960089122 TRUE
604375 960089122 TRUE
609430 960089122 TRUE
609496 960089122 TRUE
609497 960089122 TRUE
596367 960089122 TRUE
|

This is the sample data I get when I query the table. I need to update huge records. Can you pls guide?

Comment: *I have a table ...* - then you definitely have it in some **specific** DBMS. Please, do not spam tags, use the tag of **your** DBMS

Comment: Need your guidance on this

Comment: The syntax can vary by RDBMS, tag your RDBMS.

Comment: I do not see any DBMS-specific code in your example, so cannot tell what *may* be your DBMS. Please, try to figure it out by yourself, it will help you to find the correct documentation. But updatable subquery is not a general feature of SQL so the way to update depends on the DBMS

Comment: @Jenifer are you using MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server or any other

Comment: can you show a sample of your table data please? you could group by id as you are already doing and get the max t_id_pk (assuming they are integers), then feed those max primary keys into a new query selecting all your data (eg. SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRIMARY KEY IN (-- add first query here)) and use this 2nd query to run an update on the field you need?

Comment: I'm using Snowflake. I'm providing a sample of the table data here:

Comment: Could you please guide now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Can only answer based on the info you've provided on your question up to now)*

You could group by id as you are already doing and get the **max t_id_pk** (assuming they are integers), then feed those max primary keys into an update query, excluding them from processing.

Use that update query to turn all the remaining t_version_ind into FALSE.

This is best explained in the following code:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET t_version_ind = 'FALSE'
where t_id_pk NOT IN (
    SELECT t_id_pk FROM 
        (
        SELECT t_id, MAX(t_id_pk) as t_id_pk FROM T1 
        WHERE t_version_ind ='TRUE'
        GROUP BY t_id 
        HAVING count(*)>1)
        )
```

Comment: I will try this and get back. Thanks much :)

Comment: Hey Jenifer, did you try this answer and did it work?

Comment: Yes, it worked. But I have to do a bulk update. So is it necessary to add any condition? Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a bulk update. The code should work for all the duplicate rows in your table. The code already contains conditions to know which rows to update